# How do I allow any host to submit jobs in Oracle/Sun Grid Engine?

Tags: sungridengine

We have an internal network devoted to development and testing, and this network has an OGE cluster on it.  I'd like to allow any machine on that network to submit jobs, without having to add them manually one by one as submit hosts.  I've tried doing a wildcard, but it hasn't liked my syntax.  Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A qualified "no" - if you really need this, consider automating it instead.

GridEngine does not support wildcarding in host names. GE relies heavily on forward and reverse name resolution for pretty much all host interactions. You are not going to get a GridEngine cluster to blindly accept job submissions from any unspecified machine on your subnet without some bad magic.

If you use a configuration management system like Puppet or Chef, that might be the best layer to define whether a server is a submit host or not.

The alternative, brute force way(this will almost certainly violate your IT department's acceptable use policy) is using something like nmap to produce a list of hostnames on your network(if you think you can get away with it) and write a simple shell script to add each one as a submit host. This approach would require minor ongoing maintenance as the hosts on your network change over time, etc.

Comment: We don't use a management system, no.  Since the QA team spins up different VMs all the time as submit hosts, I was hoping to not go for something that requires ongoing maintenance, but...c'est la vie.  Thanks!